# how to show part of big image on mouse rollover

Tags: javascript, html, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I want when user roll over on my image it shows a part of big image of the same picture i known its possible in flash but how i don't Known ??
here is the link of the live example the site use the same technique in flash 
[click here](http://www.magictoolbox.com/magicmagnify/)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not just download the trial version from that site and look at how it is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the big image is masked with the magnifier sprite and it's moved according to the position of magnifier (to show the correct part )

Comment: still not understand will you please define me

Comment: still not understand will you please define me

Comment: @DANISH - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#mask